# Adding a render texture to a water shader graph

Tags: unity-game-engine, graph, shader, textures, render

For several weeks I have been trying to create a water shader graph with a reflection for a URP VR game. This game is being created as part of a small university course, so I don't want to invest an infinite amount of time. I have already given up on creating a "dynamic" mirror with two cameras and two render textures. I now want to add the "simple" version to my water shader graph. (one camera with one render texture and no movement) In principle, the result looks good. Unfortunately, I don't quite understand why the reflection always moves with the camera. The two screenshots should make my problem clear. I want the reflection render texture to remain rigid, but the refrection to be taken over. Has anyone had a similar case or an idea how to adjust the existing shader graph? Thanks!!!

[image: Editor view of reflection]
[image: Editor view of reflection when moving camera]
[image: shader graph part 1]
[image: shader graph part 2]

Unity Version: 2021.3.22f1
URP
VR

I am not sure what exactly is the problem. So I could only try random things.